# Getting error while deploying the model in MLRUN

Tags: mlrun

I am trying to deploy a model on `MLRun` and getting the below error.

> 2024-03-05 07:30:26,636 [info] Starting remote function deploy
> 2024-03-05 07:30:26,724 [error] error submitting build task: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://mlrun-api:8080/api/v1/build/function: details: {'reason': 'runtime error: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://nuclio-dashboard:8070/api/functions: Failed to deploy nuclio function tutorial-jovyan/tutorial-jovyan-serving Invalid Spec.Build.Registry passed, caused by: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://nuclio-dashboard:8070/api/functions'}, caused by: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://mlrun-api:8080/api/v1/build/function

Executing `MLrun` demo tutorial 3 for server deployment can lead to the replication of this problem. During the deployment of `MLrun`, one must build and push the image into the registry. This problem occurs due to the lack of mapping between the registry and the `MLrun` environment. The process of updating the registry address in `MLRun` remains ambiguous to me. Despite following the tutorial, clarity on this aspect was still lacking.